# Spring Data Rest + Spring Data Mongo - can't update numer of elements on list in object

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

so I have got a problem with updating object which contain a list of elements. My object definition:

```
public class Project {
    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private List<Pair> config;
}
```

And the Pair object:

```
public class Pair {
     private String key;
     private String value;
}
```

I'm using Spring Rest repository to provide the Rest Api and everything is stored in mongodb. Just using the simple interface to create mongoRepository

```
  @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "project", path = "projects")
  public interface ProjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Project, String>{
         Project findByName(String name);
  }
```

When I create a project object with json (sending POST to /projects):

```
 {
   "name": "test_project",
   "config": [{
     "key": "port",
     "value": "12"
   },{
     "key": "port2",
     "value": "123"
   }]
 }
```

I have got the proper response and object has been created:

```
{
  "_id": "58c916fad76a3a186731ad28",
  "name": "test_project",
  "createdAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "modifiedAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "config":[
  {
    "key": "port",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "key": "port2",
    "value": "123"
  }]
}
```

So right now I would like to send PUT to update my object and I'm getting strange results:

For example sending following body with PUT to 
     `localhost:8151/projects/58c916fad76a3a186731ad28`

```
{
  "name": "test_project",
  "config": [{
    "key": "port",
    "value": "12"
  }]
}
```

So I want to remove one element from list. The response is (Status OK):

```
 {
  "_id": "58c916fad76a3a186731ad28",
  "name": "test_project",
  "createdAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "modifiedAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "config":[
  {
    "key": "port",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "key": "port2",
    "value": "123"
  }]
}
```

So the number of elements didn't change what I expected (my expectations was that the new list replace the old one). Next test:
I would like to add one new element to list:

```
{
  "name": "test_project",
  "config": [{
    "key": "port",
    "value": "12"
  },{
    "key": "port1",
    "value": "13"
  },{
    "key": "port2",
    "value": "14"
  }]
}
```

Gives following result:

```
 {
  "_id": "58c916fad76a3a186731ad28",
  "name": "test_project",
  "createdAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "modifiedAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "config":[
  {
    "key": "port",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "key": "port1",
    "value": "13"
  }]
}
```

New element hasn't been added but the second element has changed.

It looks like instead of List mongo save it as an array and can't change the size but can update the element. Am I right?

But, if it would be true the next test should return the same result:
I'm sending the empty list of config and I'm expect that I will have an two-element list.

```
{
  "name": "test_project",
  "config": []
}
```

But what is strange for me I have got the following result:

```
 {
  "_id": "58c916fad76a3a186731ad28",
  "name": "test_project",
  "createdAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "modifiedAt": "2017-03-15T10:27:06.295+0000",
  "config":[]
}
```

So the number of elements has been updated.

To be honest right now I'm totally confused how it works. Could anyone explain how Spring rest repository handle this action and propose a proper solution for this problem?

Comment: What Spring Data Rest version you are using?

Comment: I'm using 2.5.5 version but I have tried also with the newest (2.6.1) and the problem still exists.

Comment: Could you try it with 2.5.2 version?

Comment: Nothing changed. Same problem

Comment: And also what version of spring-data-mongodb do you have?

Comment: it's 1.9.5-RELEASE

Comment: Could you please try with 1.9.3 version and 2.5.2 data rest

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. As a workaround you can send a PATCH request. This updates the array properly.